# Delphi - Implicit typecast operator not working for method parameters

Tags: arrays, delphi, record

I'm writing a kind of array wrapper, using a record as container, and including some "class-like" functions to it.
I also want the possibility to assign an array to it, as with a normal array, so I have implemented a Implicit class operator:

```
type
  TArrayWrapper = record
    class operator Implicit(AArray: array of TObject): TArrayWrapper; overload;
    Items: TArray<TObject>;

    procedure Add(AItem: TObject);
    ...
  end;
```

So I can do things like:

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  myArray: TArrayWrapper;
begin
  myArray := [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3];
  ...
end;
```

The problem appears when I try to pass an array of Integer to a method that has as parameter a TArrayWrapper:

```
procedure DoSomethingElse(AArrayWrapper: TArrayWrapper);
begin
    ...
end;


procedure DoSomething;
var
  myArray: TArrayWrapper;
begin
  myArray := [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3];
  DoSomethingElse(myArray);   <--- Works!!!!

  DoSomethingElse([Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]); <--- Error E2001: Ordinal type required -> It is considering it like a set, not as an array
end;
```

What could be happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's a compiler deficiency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has not implemented the string like operations on a dynamic array for class operators, when the record/class is used as a parameter.

<strike>There is not a QP report for this, as far as I can see.</strike> **Now there is, see below.**

A similar example is found in the comments here: [Dynamic Arrays in Delphi XE7](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014_september_dynamic_arrays_delphixe7.html)

---

A workaround:

```
DoSomethingElse(TArray<TObject>.Create(Obj1, Obj2, Obj3));
```

Or as @Stefan suggests, in order to avoid unnecessary allocations. Add a constructor to the record:

```
type
  TArrayWrapper = record
    class operator Implicit(AArray: array of TObject): TArrayWrapper; 
    constructor Init( const AArray: array of TObject);
  end;

DoSomethingElse(TArrayWrapper.Init([obj1,obj2,obj3]));
```

---

Reported as: [RSP-24610 Class operators do not accept dynamic arrays passed with brackets](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24610)

Comment: As a workaround I would rather suggest adding a ctor for the `TArrayWrapper` type with an `array of TObject` parameter than going through immediate dynamic array allocation and implicit operator call plus compiler added `CopyRecord`

Comment: @StefanGlienke, thanks. Added your suggestion to the answer. I will report this to QP later today.

Comment: I was already using this solution. The code is less elegant than just passing the array, but It works.
Thank you very much.